# How do I send email in NodeMailer only when payment is confirmed?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, nodemailer, razorpay

When I confirm the payment and the payment is verified NodeMailer must send the email to particular email id which is got from `req.body.email`. But I am getting this error and payment is done without sending an email.

Razorpay is used for payment processing.

```
Error: **No recipients defined**
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1001:34)
    at SMTPConnection.send (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:615:14)
    at sendMessage (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:227:28)        
    at D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:285:25
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1550:9)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:540:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:947:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (D:\Personal Development\Web Development\nodemailer_payment_integration\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  command: 'API'
```

[Here is my ejs file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bomyD.png)

[Here is my server side code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vxqj.png)

What can I try next?

Comment: It looks like `req.body.email` is undefined. This is unrelated to razorpay.

Comment: can you tell what should I do now because I am beginner to this your help will be great to me.

Comment: figure out why `req.body.email` is undefined

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you linked, I couldn't see any email field being passed

[image: axios code]

This causes your email field to be undefined, which causes node-mailer to throw an error. You have to pass an object with the data while posting the email, here is an example on the official site - https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example